Finding a bound using a recurrence: $Ax_{k+1}^2+Bx_{k+1}\leq Cx_k^2$
Suppose I have a recurrence $Ax_{k+1}^2+Bx_{k+1}\leq Cx_k^2$, where $A, B, C\geq 0$. Is there any way I can find a good upper bound on $x_k$? I am very new to recurrences, so I am very stuck. One thing I have tried is to rewrite the left hand side and take the log:
$$\log(x_{k+1})+\log(Ax_{k+1}+B)\leq \log(C)+2\log(x_k)$$
or
$$\log(x_{k+1})+\log(B)+\log(1+\frac{A}{B}x_{k+1})\leq \log(C)+2\log(x_k)$$
and thinking of using the inequality $\log(1+t)\geq \frac{t}{1+t}$. However, I found that this does not help and just makes it messier. Do you have any tips on how to begin?

Assuming that $x_k \ge 0$ you have $A x_{k+1}^2 \le C x_k^2$, so that $x_{k+1} \le \sqrt{C/A} x_k$ and therefore $x_{k} \le (C/A)^{n/2} x_0$. Is that good enough?

I am wondering if there is any tighter bound caused by the B term. That might be good enough for now, but I was wondering whether more sophisticated analysis could be done.

With x growing exponentially, A term will soon dwarf the B term, so the latter hardly matters at all.

By the same logic, does that mean we can write $Bx_{k+1}\leq Cx_{k}^2$, leading to quadratic convergence?
